# Json file to pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to work with JSON file on spark (pyspark) environment.

Problem: Unable to convert JSON to expected format in Pyspark Dataframe

**1st Input data set:**

> https://health.data.ny.gov/api/views/cnih-y5dw/rows.json

In this file metadata is defined at start for of the file with tag "meta" and then followed by data with tag "data".

FYI: Steps taken to download data from web to local drive. 1. I've downloaded file to my local drive 2. then pushed to hdfs - from there I'm reading it to spark environment.

```
df=sqlContext.read.json("/user/train/ny.json",multiLine=True)
df.count()
out[5]: 1
df.show()
```

[image]

`df.printSchema()`

```
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- meta: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- view: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- attribution: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- attributionLink: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- averageRating: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- columns: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- cachedContents: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- average: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- largest: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- non_null: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- null: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- smallest: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- sum: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- top: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- item: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dataTypeName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- fieldName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- flags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- format: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- align: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- mask: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- noCommas: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- precisionStyle: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- position: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- renderTypeName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- tableColumnId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- width: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- createdAt: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- displayType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- downloadCount: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- flags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- grants: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- flags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- inherited: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- hideFromCatalog: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- hideFromDataJson: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- indexUpdatedAt: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- attachments: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- assetId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- blobId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- filename: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- availableDisplayTypes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- custom_fields: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Additional Resources: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- See Also: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Dataset Information: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Agency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Dataset Summary: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Contact Information: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Coverage: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Data Frequency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Dataset Owner: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Granularity: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Organization: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Posting Frequency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Time Period: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Units: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Disclaimers: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Limitations: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Local Data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- County Filter: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- County_Column: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- filterCondition: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- children: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- includeAuto: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- multiSelect: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- operator: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- tableColumnId: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- 583607: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- advanced: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- unifiedVersion: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- jsonQuery: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- order: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ascending: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- columnFieldName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- rdfSubject: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- renderTypeConfig: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- visible: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- table: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- rowLabel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- newBackend: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- numberOfComments: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- oid: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- owner: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- flags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- profileImageUrlLarge: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- profileImageUrlMedium: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- profileImageUrlSmall: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- screenName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- provenance: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- publicationAppendEnabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- publicationDate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- publicationGroup: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- publicationStage: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- query: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- orderBys: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- ascending: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- expression: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- columnId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rights: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- rowsUpdatedAt: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rowsUpdatedBy: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tableAuthor: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- flags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- profileImageUrlLarge: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- profileImageUrlMedium: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- profileImageUrlSmall: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- screenName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tableId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- totalTimesRated: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- viewCount: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- viewLastModified: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- viewType: string (nullable = true)
```

***Problem:***  All records getting wrapped up in single row and two column, i.e meta and data. Also with spark native JSON utility - Spark infers the schema (meatadata) automatically - and my expectation is it shouldn't explicitly as separate column on dataframe.

**Expected Output**
JSON data set has following list of columns. It should show them in tabular format in dataframe where I can query them"

```
FACILITY, ADDRESS, LAST INSPECTED, VIOLATIONS,TOTAL  CRITICAL VIOLATIONS, TOTAL CRIT.  NOT CORRECTED, TOTAL  NONCRITICAL VIOLATIONS, DESCRIPTION, LOCAL HEALTH DEPARTMENT, COUNTY, FACILITY ADDRESS, CITY, ZIP CODE, NYSDOH GAZETTEER (1980), MUNICIPALITY, OPERATION NAME, PERMIT EXPIRATION DATE, PERMITTED  (D/B/A), PERMITTED  CORP. NAME,PERM. OPERATOR LAST NAME, PERM. OPERATOR LAST NAME, PERM. OPERATOR FIRST NAME, NYS HEALTH OPERATION ID, INSPECTION TYPE, INSPECTION COMMENTS, FOOD SERVICE FACILITY STATE, Location1
```

**2nd Input DataSet:**
On site, it's first data set about funded projects by world bank

> http://jsonstudio.com/resources/
>
> (On site, it's first data set about funded projects by world bank)

*It works all fine.*

```
df=sqlContext.read.json("/user/train/wb.json")
df.count()
500
```

2nd Input Data Sets works all but 1st Input dataset is not. My Observation is the way metadata defined is different for both Json files. In 1st. Meta data is defined first and then data however in 2nd file - meatadate is available with data on every line.

Can you please guide me on 1st input JSON file format and how to handle situation while converting it into pyspark dataframe?

**Updated Outcome:** After initial analysis we found that format seems wrong but community member helped an alternative way to read format. Marking answer as right and closing this thread.

Let me know if you need any further details, thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of spark are you using?

Comment: why this is a problem `Problem: All records getting wrapped up in single row and two column, i.e meta and data.`? looking at your json data. the dataframe formed looks correct. Can you specify your expected output and explain why that is a problem?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan thanks for your response. May be you are right and i'm missing any of steps in between. My expectation is native JSON utility should read metadata to format "data" output records. It should not show meta as one of output column. If you see output produce by Steven Black for 2nd input data set, in below comment - on databricks notebook - my expectation it should produce same output.

Comment: you already have the same output as he has for the second dataframe.  for the second dataframe the json is simple and plain so you have data for each columns. but for the first dataframe the json file has nested structure so the dataframe is complex. So what you should do is clarify what your expected dataframe from the json input you have. and update the question according to that

Comment: @RameshMaharjan - fyi 1. I've updated schema in or original post 2. Add more details to problem statement. Does it help. I'm adding sample expected output, shortly.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan added expected outputformat as well.  Now, Please suggest how to approach it, thank you.

Comment: I don't see such fields in data which are all array types

Comment: not sure, if I understood you - can you please elaborate. My point is meta data is there and data is also there. Just need some steps where spark would able to read it thru by it self and give expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out my notebook on [databricks](https://community.cloud.databricks.com)

https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/753971180331031/2636709537891264/8469274372247319/latest.html

The first dataset is corrupt, i.e. it's not valid `json` and so spark can't read it.

But this was for spark 2.2.1

This is especially confusing because of the way this `json` file is organized
The data is stored as a list of lists

```
df=spark.read.json("rows.json",multiLine=True)
data = df.select("data").collect()[0]['data']
```

And the column names are stored separately

```
column_names = map(lambda x: x['fieldName'], df.select("meta").collect()[0][0][0][4])
```

Comment: thanks for detail explanation. It helps a lot.   However I'm not sure if it's corrupt or I'm  missing on any of steps. This is posted on gov site used by many online forums and data scientist. Further, when I try reading it with JSON utility, with multiLine=True `df=sqlContext.read.json("/user/train/ny.json",multiLine=True)`  it gives me the output thought but not expected format as it has given to you with 2nd input file.

Comment: Yup, at least in my case it's because spark hasn't been given valid `json`. It looks like the whole file is 23 MB and may not have fully downloaded though!

Comment: I think, file is valid. It's just that we need right steps to read thru it. Example if I follow below code it gives me all data column. Now I just have to find a way to separate each column and tag a name to it.  `from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df=sqlContext.read.json("/user/train/ny.json",multiLine=True)
df.select(explode("data")).show(1,truncate=False)`

Comment: wow! I see... the data is stored in as a `list` of lists in a `row` in the data column. The headers are probably stored somewhere in the meta column

Comment: I'm updating the databricks notebook so you can see my walkthrough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167281/discussion-between-steven-black-and-user2763088).

Comment: I'm not sure if the link the the databricks notebook has changed, but here is the final version with the code to make a correctly formatted dataframe https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/753971180331031/2636709537891264/8469274372247319/latest.html