# Write result of api to a data lake with Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am using the below code to make an api call.

```
import requests   
response = requests.get('https://myapi.com/api/v1/city', auth=('user', 'password'))
data = response.json()
```

Would like to save the json payload as a json document in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 and read the document from here.

```
data.write.json("wasbs://<file_system>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/city.json")
```

**Error:** *AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the json list `data` variable into dataframe either by using

[**`df=spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448473/pyspark-convert-a-standard-list-to-data-frame), [**`df=spark.read.json(data)`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396558/json-file-to-pyspark-dataframe)

Then write to Azure DataLake Storage using

`df.write.json("wasbs://<file_system>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/city.json")`

**`Or`** if you don't want to convert to **`json`** then use

`spark.createDataFrame(data,schema).saveAsTextFile("<path>")`

---

**Update:**

Try by creating dataframe by using **`Row`** object.

**`Example:`**

```
data=[{'id': 1}]

from pyspark.sql import *

df=spark.createDataFrame([Row(**i) for i in data])
df.show()
#+---+
#| id|
#+---+
#|  1|
#+---+

df.write.json("<path>")
```

Comment: Hi @484, When I use `df=spark.read.json(data)
df.write.json("wasbs://fdmtestfileshare@entedatdevdl.dfs.core.windows.net/building.json")` get the following error. 
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.util.HashMap

Comment: @paone, Please check my edited answer **`Update`** section as we are creating dataframe then writing to storage.